# Minkowski's Inequality For Infinite Sum.

Tags: functional-analysis

Minkowski's inequality for infinite sum(where it ranges from zero to infinity), is the proof the same with the Minkowski's inequality(where the sum is finite e.g 0 to n) ?
If they are not the same, then how can the Minkowski's inequality for infinite sum be proved?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually build on the known result from $\mathbb{C}^n$. That is, for every $k>0$ one has:
$$\left(\sum_{j\leq k}|x_j+y_j|^p\right)^{1/p}\leq \left(\sum_{j\leq k}|x_j|^p\right)^{1/p} + \left(\sum_{j\leq k}|y_j|^p\right)^{1/p} \leq \left(\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}}|x_j|^p\right)^{1/p} + \left(\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}}|y_j|^p\right)^{1/p},$$
implying that $x+y\in l^p(\mathbb{N})$ and
$$\left(\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}}|x_j+y_j|^p\right)^{1/p} = \limsup_k\left(\sum_{j\leq k}|x_j+y_j|^p\right)^{1/p}\leq  \left(\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}}|x_j|^p\right)^{1/p} + \left(\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}}|y_j|^p\right)^{1/p}.$$

Comment: I've been looking for a proof of exactly this but I don't understand much in the second line. For example, why does $x+y$  belong to $l^{p}(N)$ and why is it equal to limsup rather than than limit. Thanks.

Comment: @markleeds for a non-decreasing sequence, $\limsup = \lim$. Writing it that way for the partial sums has two (cosmetic) benefits: (a) $\lim S_k=\infty$ is awkward: some texts refer to that as convergence only in "a wide sense", or even divergence; $\limsup S_k=\infty$ is well understood. Hence, when a priori unsure if a series converges, using $\limsup$ requires less explanations. (b) If for all $k$ we have $S_k\leq L$, then we know that $\limsup S_k \leq L$ as well.